# How to add cart entries in newly-created CartModel?

Tags: spring, sap-commerce-cloud

I used following code to create a cart and add one cartEntry inside this CartModel:

```
final CartModel cartModel = cartFactory.createCart() ;
OrderEntryModel orderEntryModel = new OrderEntryModel();
List<AbstractOrderEntryModel> entryModel = new ArrayList<>();
final ProductModel product = productService.getProductForCode(productCode); // came from another method
orderEntryModel.setProduct(product);
entryModel.add(orderEntryModel);
cartModel.setEntries(entryModel);
cartModel.setUser(userService.getCurrentUser());
cartService.setSessionCart(cartModel);
```

When I try to get this cart from session, apply this cart, and pass this cart to next another OOTB method, I get the following exception:

```
DefultAbstractOrderEntryPreparer@1090ef7e]: unexpected preparer error: null] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at de.hybris.platform.order.interceptors.DefaultAbstractOrderEntryPreparer.onPrepare(DefaultAbstractOrderEntryPreparer.java:97)
```

After debugging, I got to know that this issue occurs because I am adding order entries in a different way than what we used in a normal checkout flow (first code block , third last line) .

**So, is there any OOTB method or any other way to create an orderEntry and add it to a newly-created cart?**

I checked for normal cart created during Checkout flow, and this issue doesn't happen. So, I came to a conclusion that this occurs because of following code from the first code block:

```
OrderEntryModel orderEntryModel = new OrderEntryModel();
List<AbstractOrderEntryModel> entryModel = new ArrayList<>();
final ProductModel product = productService.getProductForCode(productCode); // came from another method
orderEntryModel.setProduct(product);
entryModel.add(orderEntryModel);
cartModel.setEntries(entryModel);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a standard service called cartService, that as addNewEntry method.

```
        final CartModel cartModel = cartFactory.createCart();
        final ProductModel product = productService.getProductForCode(productCode); // came from another method
        getCartService().addNewEntry(cartModel, product, 1, null);
        cartModel.setUser(userService.getCurrentUser());
        cartService.setSessionCart(cartModel);
```

Comment: Hi @Fransico , I saw following method related to this flow inside CartService.  :                                    addToCart(CartModel cart, ProductModel product, long quantity, UnitModel unit)

Comment: @Jemie Try `addNewEntry`. `addToCart` is deprecated. Let us know if it works.

Comment: @Jemie, geffchang is right. AddToCart is deprecated since version 6.2

Comment: Thanks @FranciscoSilva and geffchang.. It works for me , now I am able to process with newly added cart entry.